# Spring batch doesnt execute drop script

Tags: spring-batch, metatable

Im tryin to configure spring batch to run schema and drop script:

```
batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.PostgreSQLSequenceMaxValueIncrementer
batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-postgresql.sql
batch.drop.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-postgresql.sql
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=false
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=
batch.data.source.init=true
batch.table.prefix=BATCH_
```

At the start of the, it creates the tables but apparently it doesnt excecute drop script because data is always there.

Am using :
- spring batch 3.0.8
- spring boot 1.5.10

Any ideas ?

Thanks